# C socket Client communicate with Server outside LAN without knowing IP address

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, client-server

I write a small game using socket in which multiple clients join the game, everything works in the LAN. Now I want to extend to clients outside LAN, what I wonder is: if I don't know the IP address of the client then will the program work?

Inside LAN I use:

`char *ip = "127.0.0.1";`

Comment: *"Inside LAN I use: `char *ip = "127.0.0.1";`"* - that's not "inside LAN", that is a loopback address, which means your program only works if all instances of your program are *on the same machine*, which is stricter than saying "on the same LAN" (and potentially different machines). In any case, no, it won't work without knowing the IP to connect to. You need to know or implement some mechanism to share it.

Comment: you mean that I need to know both IP address of Client and Server? can you suggest me some mechanism to share IP-address wihtout "directly" asking client about his/her address?

Comment: You have just found out one reason why multiplayer games connect to central servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client needs to know the server's IP in order to connect to it.

If the client and server run on the same machine, the server can listen on `127.0.0.1` and the client can connect to that IP.

If the client and server run on the same LAN, the server needs to listen on the NIC that is connected to the LAN, and the client can connect to the server's LAN IP.

If the client is running on a different network and wants to connect to the server over the Internet, the client must connect to the server's public Internet IP, as assigned by the server's ISP.  And if the server is running behind a NAT router, the public IP is assigned to the router and not the server directly, so the router must have **port forwarding** configured to route incoming connections to the server machine on the router's LAN.

If the client doesn't know the IP to connect to, the server will need to publish its IP somewhere that the client can query it, such as via DNS, a website, a central public server that all clients connect to for relaying, etc.